# Still getting 407 from Proxy after CONNECT

Tags: networking, proxy, internet-connection

I'm in a corporate network that access to the Internet through a proxy.
For instance I have connection to the Internet through the browsers (Firefox, Chrome ...)

The problem is that when I’m trying to connect from the Terminal and set the `export` configuration for both (`http` and `https`) like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@ip:port
```

And I try to make a git clone like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife
```

I get:

> Cloning into 'Spoon-Knife'...
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/':
>   Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

#### Some things to note

- I try to access using other commands like curl 
  `curl www.google.com` 
  and still get

> Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. The ISA Server requires
>   authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter
>   is denied. (12209)

- Like I say my Internet connection in the browser works perfectly well. So isn’t a connection issue.
- The only special character that my password has is a `*` and I escaped it properly using `%2A`.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure your proxy is using basic auth? It is likely to be NTLM, being ISA.

Not 100% on how git handles proxies, and auth thereof, but if we can get curl working we will have half a chance of working back to making git behave.

Can you try using ntlm and, if that doesn't work, negotiate on the commandline with curl - check the man page [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), but you'll need

> --proxy-ntlm

and

> -U user:password

Be careful with escaping your "*" in your pw (or change it, at least temporarily to make troubleshooting easier)

If it's NTLM, you're out of luck with git I *think* - but [a question over on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060437/configuring-git-on-windows-to-use-ntlm-proxy-authentication) suggests an intermediate proxy on your local box - [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) - which I have used to NTLM wrap other software that can't do auth.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but when i do curl with `-U user:password` it returns fine without error. So then how to make `git clone` behave? Doesn't look like Git has a `--proxy` option.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783659/does-git-clone-work-through-ntlm-proxies appears to suggest you can use NTLM with a reasonably recent git - or indeed I suspect basic auth.